# Conditional SELECT COUNT(id) using COUNT(id) as the condition?

Tags: sql-server, count

I want to select only the category IDs where the number of articles assigned to the category is more than 3.

I've tried various permutations and posted the one below that I feel most clearly explains what I'm trying to do, although I have a feeling I need to use a nested SELECT. I have tried nested SELECTs but with no success.

```
SELECT categoryID, COUNT(articleID) AS numArticles 
FROM articles GROUP BY categoryID WHERE numArticles > 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [having](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx)

```
SELECT categoryID, COUNT(articleID) AS numArticles 
FROM articles GROUP BY categoryID HAVING COUNT(articleID) > 3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT categoryID, COUNT(articleID) AS numArticles 
FROM articles GROUP BY categoryID 
HAVING COUNT(articleID) > 3
```

Comment: HAVING is the key, but your example gives the error, "Invalid column name 'numArticles'".

Comment: sorry, not used to mssql syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Having](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) clause

```
Select CategoryId, Count(ArticleId) as numArticles
From dbo.Articles
Group By CategoryId
Having Count(ArticleId) > 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`HAVING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) clause:

```
SELECT categoryID, COUNT(articleID) AS numArticles 
FROM articles 
 GROUP BY categoryID 
 HAVING COUNT(articleID) > 3
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx):

> Specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate. HAVING can be used only with the SELECT statement. HAVING is typically used in a GROUP BY clause. When GROUP BY is not used, HAVING behaves like a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use HAVING instead.

http://techonthenet.com/sql/having.php

Answer (score 0):

For this don't use WHERE, you have to use HAVING instead.

Try this:

```
SELECT categoryID, COUNT(articleID) AS numArticles 
FROM articles GROUP BY categoryID HAVING numArticles > 3
```